# Win XP HDD's ownership rights were ruined after using "Take Ownership" from another computer

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, permissions

An old friend of mine recently found an old 80gb HDD and he gave it to me and said he asked if I could copy his old data from it.
So I got home, plugged in the drive and started copying from the drive. However, I realized that Windows would not let me copy C:\Documents and Settings"User" ("user" part is his name so I'm typing it this way)
So I tried using a small .reg file that allows one to take ownership of pretty much any file or directory, which went well. However, I finally realized that I had made a huge mistake when I tried to pass the HDD through VMWare Player to boot up Windows XP. I had error messages telling me that Windows failed to load the account and it would use the "Default" user account to log in, and after clicking OK I still got to the desktop, but now I had another error "C:\Documents and Settings"User" access is denied" and and as a result, desktop icons won't show up, the wallpaper is blank (because the wallpaper is tied to Windows Live Photos which is also tied to this directory) so now I'm stuck in this situation. I tried using the same .reg file on VM, but it doesn't work.
Is there any way I can claim the user rights back?

Edit: I managed to re-claim the ownership through the VM and now programs and desktop icons are loading properly.
It seems this incident was a lesson for me. Thank you for the helpful advice!
By the way, I understand the downvotes, I've heard it's a common thing for new users like me.

Comment: Unclear: First, if you added a disk it certainly cannot be called `C:`. Second, you can't take ownership of a folder with a `.reg` file, so I don't understand at all what you did.

Comment: I don't know. It is normally easy to get data from an XP HDD.  Can you reverse your steps?

Comment: I'm guessing the .reg file was one that adds a right-click menu item to run 'takeown'.

Comment: Just rescue all the data from it, give that to him and don't try to make Windows XP working again. If it is not his old drive, the who knows, it may contain a virus.

Comment: @harrymc Ah, I apologize for the confusion, yeah the letter was different.
I assume that now my PC is the "owner" of the documents folder. I already have the necessary files (photos, videos, games etc) copied but I just wanted to have a look at the nostalgic desktop last used in 2009.

Comment: Maybe if you opened the .reg file and revert what it changed.  However, depending on what exactly the reg file did that could be hard or impossible to determine the original values.  How big is the .reg file?  Can it be posted here?

Comment: @cybernard, registry changes will not change filesystem permissions. It seems more likely the reg file may add some right-click menu, like grawity suggests, to make the TakeOwn process more accessible.

Comment: I know and agree that the registry can't change file system permissions.  However, without seeing the registry file we can't know what kind of hack they did.  We can only assume that it was as innocent as adding the "TakeOwn" process to the right click menu.  Assuming things can be dangerous.

Comment: However, the whole "failed to load windows profile" suggests that is damaged or replaced the user.dat file in the profile directory.

Comment: @cybernard Indeed, the "failed to load profile" issue persists. Although it's not really much of an issue as everything works properly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once file permissions are broken inside a user's profile it is close to impossible to correct them. While it may be possible to go through common folders and find and set the correct permissions, any folders created by or for any other software may not be so well documented or have a reference for comparison. OS repairs may not even work to resolve this, as they also lack knowledge of what permissions actually need to be for the state that particular OS is supposed to be in.

Adjusting permissions during a file recovery attempt is nearly always a destructive process. This is one reason why the recommended process for data recovery is to create an image of the drive you are recovering and work from that image, rather than working from the drive itself.

Simply taking ownership back is unlikely to solve the issue either, because ownership only gives you the *right* to adjust permissions on files or folders, and not every file or folder needs to be the same permission, even inside the user's profile folder, so even owning the files, you still need to correct the permissions on them.